# Regex match multiple strings on same line

Tags: regex, bash

I'm using a regex to process a field in the following format:

```
52.200.238.131 - - [31/Jan/2017:10:30:21 +0000] "POST /v1/articles?key=sEahu58asdasd
```

I want to extract just the date and key using regex. My attempt is the following:

```
cat Downloads/testlog.log | grep -oE '\[[0-9]{2}/[A-Za-z0-9]{3}/[0-9]{4}|key=[A-Za-z0-9]+'
```

My output prints the two matched strings on two different lines:

```
key=sEahu58nYBTJa
[31/Jan/2017
```

How can I get them to print on the same line?

```
key=sEahu58nYBTJa [31/Jan/2017
```

Comment: Maybe with sed? [`sed -E 's#.*(\[[0-9]{2}/[A-Za-z0-9]{3}/[0-9]{4}).*(key=[A-Za-z0-9]+).*#\2 \1#'`](https://ideone.com/ebH9Sr)

Comment: Or, try adding `| tr -d '\n'` after your `grep` command.

Comment: The first command retrun everything on the line

Comment: Yes, see the first option in my answer. `sed` approach will only work when the values are always present in the input.

Comment: the second doesn't work for me because i juts want to remove the new  line between the date and key. Not between every match in the file.

Comment: Wait, did you check [`grep -oE '\[[0-9]{2}/[A-Za-z0-9]{3}/[0-9]{4}|key=[A-Za-z0-9]+' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`](https://ideone.com/ebH9Sr)?

Comment: Why is the order of the matches the wrong way round?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ grep -oP '\d{2}/\w{3}/\d{4}|key=\w+' Downloads/testlog.log | paste -d' ' - -
31/Jan/2017 key=sEahu58asdasd
```

Comment: Paste is very elegant. ;I would use `paste -d' ' - -` to just paste  2 lines. There's most likely many lines in that file, and you don't want the output to be one gigantic line.

Answer (score 1):

You may use two approaches here.

The first one is by using the additional `sed` piped command to replace the newlines with a space (see [Kenneth L's answer @superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1008415)):

```
s='52.200.238.131 - - [31/Jan/2017:10:30:21 +0000] "POST /v1/articles?key=sEahu58asdasd'
echo $s | grep -oE '\[[0-9]{2}/[A-Za-z0-9]{3}/[0-9]{4}|key=[A-Za-z0-9]+' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/iAw2gr)

However, it outputs `[31/Jan/2017 key=sEahu58asdasd` since the first match is `[31/Jan/2017`.

You may also use the following `sed` solution *if you know the values are always there*:

```
sed -E 's#.*(\[[0-9]{2}/[A-Za-z0-9]{3}/[0-9]{4}).*(key=[A-Za-z0-9]+).*#\2 \1#'
```

See [another online demo](https://ideone.com/ebH9Sr)

The point is to match and capture the parts you need and just match those you need to remove, and replace with the replacement backreferences, `\2` and `\1` that reference the values captured with the corresponding capturing groups.