# sed command in Solaris server

Tags: shell, sed, solaris

I have many javascript files in my solaris server which have some debug, print and trace statements which I want to comment. There are hundreds of file like this.
I have found a script to do this but the problem is the script is removing the urhk_b2k_printRepos statement instead of commenting it. The script is as below:

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "usage: prdel <script file name> <directory in which scripts are present>"
    exit 1
fi

file=$1
dir=$2

if [ ! -s ${file} ]
then
    echo "script file ${file} either does not exist or is empty (zero bytes)"
    echo "Exiting..."
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d ${dir} ]
then
    echo "Invalid directory ${dir} entered"
    echo "Exiting..."
    exit 1
fi

cordir="./corrected"
prlogdir="./prlog"
if [ -d ${cordir} ]
then
    echo "The corrected directory exist in the path, Please remove and run the tool again"
    echo "Exiting..."
    exit 1
else
    mkdir ${cordir}
fi

if [ -d ${prlogdir} ]
then
    echo "The prlog directory exist in the path, Please remove and run the tool again"
    echo "Exiting..."
    exit 1
else
    mkdir ${prlogdir}
fi
errFile="$prlogdir/scr_err.rpt"
sucFile="$prlogdir/scr_suc.rpt"
Lines=`wc -l $file`
cntr=1
while [ $cntr -le $Lines ]
do
    src=`head -$cntr $file|tail -1`
    echo "$cntr. Processing $src...."
    srcPath="${dir}/${src}"
    if [ ! -s ${srcPath} ]
    then
        echo "Script file ${src} does not exist in the path given" >> ${errFile}
    else
        cp $srcPath $cordir/$src.tmp
        srctemp="$cordir/$src.tmp"
        srccor="$cordir/$src.corrected"
        printcnt=`grep -ci "^[  ]*print" $srctemp`
        if [ $printcnt -ne 0 ]
        then
            cat $srctemp|sed 's/^[  ]*[  ]*print[ ]*(/#print(/'|sed 's/^[   ]*[  ]*PRINT[ ]*(/#PRINT(/' > $srccor   
            mv $srccor $srctemp
        fi
        prreposcnt=`grep -ci "printrepos" $srctemp`
        if [ $prreposcnt -ne 0 ]
        then
            cat $srctemp|sed 's/^.*urhk_b2k_printRepos.*/#Printrepos statement removed/'|sed 's/^.*urhk_B2k_PrintRepos.*/#Printrepos statement removed/'|sed 's/^.*urhk_B2k_printRepos.*/#Printrepos statement removed/'|sed 's/^.*urhk_b2k_PrintRepos.*/#Printrepos statement removed/' > $srccor
        else
            cp $srctemp $srccor
        fi
        echo "Script file $src correction is done" >> ${sucFile}
        rm $srctemp
        diff $srcPath $srccor >> $prlogdir/$src.diff.rpt
    fi
    cntr=`expr $cntr + 1`
done
echo "done"
```

I am completely new to shell scripting. Can anyone help me to modify this script to comment "urhk_b2k_printRepos" lines and also comment "TRACE ON" lines.

Comment: you need to boil your problem down to the **one line** of code that is causing your problem. Do you see it? Then you can focus on understanding just that bit of `sed` code (hint, hint). Read thru the `sed` tutorial at https://grymoir.com/Unix/Sed.html and you should understand why it is failing. Think about what a `substitute` command should be/is doing. Good luck.

Comment: Notice how this Q ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075540/regex-match-multiple-strings-on-same-line/47076526#47076526 ) shows sample input, expected output and attempt to solve the problem. These are the qualities that help get your Q answered in a timely fashion. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: The line is actually like this sv_q = urhk_b2k_printRepos(MOD1); which I want to change to #sv_q = urhk_b2k_printRepos(MOD1);

Comment: yes, now you can experiment with `echo " sv_q = urhk_b2k_printRepos(MOD1);  | sed '/ sv_q = urhk_b2k_printRepos/s/^/#/'` . When that is working as needed, then you can see what changes you need to make to use it in your larger script. Good luck.